# Ignoring parent node in XML using XMLReader in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file from which I have to extract some specific nodes and put them in a SQL table.

I am using XmlReader and have switch case on XmlReader.Name

Here is just a sample one with very few nodes just for explanation.

```
<products>
   <product>
       <description>Nothing</description>
       <cost>$34.78</cost>
       <inventory>166</inventory>
   </product>
   <product>
       <description>Nike Cap 17893</description>
       <cost>$29.99</cost>
       <inventory>54</inventory>
   </product>
</products>
```

The idea is if there is Nothing in description node, I should ignore the entire product and move to the next product.

I wanted to use XmlReader.Skip() in that case but it seems it only skips the chidren nodes but the parents nodes.

Just wondering if C# provides any method to ignore parent node?

Comment: how big is this xml file ? can't you use Linq to XML ?

Comment: The XML file will typically have 10,000 to 12,000 products

Comment: @bluepiranha: That still sounds like you should easily be able to load it into memory, which would make it *much* easier to handle than with XmlReader.

Comment: @JonSkeet Pardon my noviceness, but when you say load it into memory, what C# API class do you suggest me to read the XML file?

Comment: Use LINQ to XML, as suggested by Selman22, e.g. `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("products.xml")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq To Xml you could easily ignore all Elements that are "Nothing" and just process the other elements.

Here is quick Example.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("file.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> productsWithoutNothing = from product in root.Elements("product")
                                               where (string)product.Element("description") != "Nothing"
                                               select product;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much easier if you use XSL to filter the nodes.

Step 1: Use XSL to get a list of (parent) nodes which has description

Step 2: Loop through this filtered set